# Should a class name reflect the class itself or instances of the class?

Tags: naming-conventions

I have a class named 'Material'

The class itself represents an effect, but instances of that class represent a material.

Should I call the class 'Effect' or 'Material' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) and make two classes for two represented concerns.

Answer (score 1):

What environment are you working in?

I'd keep both class and instances of classes representative of the material and employ a subclass for effect - particularly if the effect is coupled tightly with the material as is often the case. This will allow for better management as your effect arrays become more sophisticated.

Comment: visual studio, but I don't see how it matters?
You're probably right, the situation I'm having is most likely because I have bad design.

Comment: http://10rem.net/articles/net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices - based on best-practices I'd encourage the same logic as for creating and appending 'Collections' 'Exceptions' etc onto your class names - simply for easier visual recognition. No rocket-science logic on my end... quite possible there isn't a value in organizing things in that nature for your specific project. Best of luck!